# List Iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have been looking for the same problem I have with iterators; and I found a lot of topics with almost the same title, and similar problems, but mine is a little bit different.

I'm trying to get the *iterator at a specific position, but I get the error:
"list iterator not deferencable" at run time, here is my code:

```
 CompetidorFormula2000* retornarCompetidorF2000(int pos){
        list<Competidor*>::iterator itr=miLista.begin();
        CompetidorFormula2000* f1=new CompetidorFormula2000(); 

        if(pos>0 && pos<=miLista.size()){
            advance(itr,pos);

        }
        f1=(CompetidorFormula2000*) (*itr);
        return f1;
        delete f1;
    }
```

Comment: Erm, not related to the problem you describe, but anything that comes after `return` doesn't execute, so the object pointed to by `f1` is never deallocated and just leaks.

Comment: Not related to that error message, but why are you allocating a new object and then re-assigning something else to that pointer (leaking memory). Also, no code after the return will get called, so the delete will not do anything (but if it did, that would be bad).

Answer (score 3):

If `pos` equals `miLista.size()` then you will get an iterator to the end of the list, the same iterator you get when you call `miLista.end()`. An iterator to the end of the list is *not dereferenceable*.

Comment: damn the delete f1; was an old typo, It worked changing the if(pos>0 && pos<=miLista.size()) to if(pos>0 && pos<miLista.size());

Comment: @José Del Valle: I believe that should be `if(pos>=0 && pos<miLista.size())`